# upgrade:upgradation failed,13.10 issue

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 13.10

I was upgrading 13.04 to 13.10.And suddenly it hanged and upper part of the screen went black.
So I stopped the upgradation and unfortunately I forcefully shutdown.But its already upgraded to 13.10(I feel upgradation is not complete though)

**Problems**
The desktop flickers now and sometimes the screen turns black.

Sound stopped.No sound output detected in sound settings.And the shutdown button also not working.

**Is there a way to upgrade it again to 13.10(completely)?**

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl + Alt + F5 . login in . run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo dpkg --configure -a` .